# 22.04 update now requires 2 login attempts

Tags: login

After recent updates the login screen from either a reboot or after suspend requires 2 attempts with the password. Even after enabling view password and carefully checking the correct details it still spends 10s or so on both attempts to finally login!

My Dell Latitude Plus 7620 is using the 5.19.0-50-generic kernel.

Is this a bug or have I screwed something?